# What does this syntax mean in google developer tools?

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I am familiar with console errors where the GET fails to find a given file and the error message spits out the name of the file it can't find. But in this case, the file is still there and I am getting a GET error like this in chrome developer tools:

```
javascript%22
/static/js/views/search_input.js=%22text
```

What does this mean?

Comment: %22 is " when urlencoded - have you messed up a string somewhere and accidently included an errant " ? (That's a " (speechmark) by the way, not '' which is two apostrophes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search your code for a link, window.open or xhr request to the url:

```
 javascript:"/static/js/views/search_input.js="text
```

It looks like a link but could as well be a template for rendering.

The idea was probably to concatenation two strings,

"/static/js/views/search_input.js?"+text

It's therefore probably a bug in an attempt to an Ajax request for search.